# How do I change Grafana docker container environment variables on AWS Fargate to use a mysql database

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, grafana

How do I change Grafana Docker container environment variables on AWS Fargate to use a mysql database? I am very new to AWS and containers. Is it through the cmd line? When I type "docker ps -a" my containers do not show up. I've tried looking through the Grafana documentation but I think that's if you are running the containers locally. Would it be the same for AWS? I've looked into SSHing into the containers, but that requires me to alter the task definition in Terraform.

Comment: You mean using mysql as a data source like this? https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/

Comment: I edited your question, this isn't reddit

Comment: No, not as a data source, as the default database. Out of the box it uses litesql for storing usernames and such. To switch the default db, it requires one to overwrite the environmental variables. I guess my question is can someone please tell me in plain English how to overwrite the environmental variables for a grafana docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define [correct variables in the ECS task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html), e.g.:

```
GF_DATABASE_TYPE: mysql
GF_DATABASE_HOST: my-mysql:3306
GF_DATABASE_USER: my-user
GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD: my-password
```

Of course you may need to more if you have specific DB configuration. All options are documented: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#database

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I did not realize you can add env vars to the task def!